# PyLint does not see installed modules since upgrading to Python 3.8

Tags: python, vim, pylint, neovim, python-3.8

I am using the coc.nvim IntelliSense engine in neovim together with the Python linter Pylint. Since upgrading from Python 3.7 to 3.8,
pylint doesn't see my installed modules.

I installed pylint with `pip3 install pylint` and linked it to coc using the vim command `:CocInstall coc-python`. This worked flawlessly before upgrading to Python 3.8.

If I now try to import e.g. numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

coc displays the error message

```
[pylint E0401] [E] Unable to import 'numpy' (import-error)
```

Running the code does not lead to any errors, so the problem should not be with Python or numpy. Also, coc works without problems in other filetypes (e.g. JS or LaTeX), so it has to do something with Pylint not being configured for Python 3.8.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Stupid questions: 1. Is numpy installed for Python 3.8? 2. Does it recognize other 3rd party imports? 3. Does it work with any other version than 2.7, such as Python 3.7 for example?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. No, e.g. importing Matplotlib leads to the same result 3. It worked with 3.7